# What to use instead of bind-attr helper in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

When I want to use bind-attr helper on the simple table data argument ().
To change the color of that column it writes an error on console:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

-Here is my index.hbs:

```html
   <table id="t01">
          <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Headquarters</th> 
            <th>revenue</th>
          </tr>
          {{#each model as |index|}}
            <tr>
       <td>  {{index.name}} </td>
       <td {{bind-attr class="className"}}>          {{index.headquarters}} </td>
       <td>  {{index.revenue}} </td>
            </tr>
          {{/each}}
    </table>
    <button {{action "toggleColor"}}> Change color </button>
```

-And here is my index.js controller:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';


export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  className:"red",
  actions:{
    toggleColor: function(){
      if(this.get("className") == "red"){
        this.set("className","blue");  
      }else{
        this.set("className","red");  
      }
      
    }
  }
});
```

-Does anyone has any idea what is wrong? It doesn't even show the values in the table that would actually show if I didn't use the bind-attr.

UPDATE:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return [{
      "name" : "Google",
      "headquarters": "Mountain View, California, United States of America",
      "revenue":"59825000000"
      },{
        "name" : "Facebook",
        "headquarters":"Menlo Park, California,United States of America",
        "revenue":"7870000000"
      },{
        "name" : "twitter",
        "revenue": "664000000",
        "headquarters":"San Francisco, California, United States of America"
      }];
  }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6F2k.png)

Comment: className property is changing but you haven't defined any class for red or blue to see the effect. In this [twiddle i prepared for you](https://ember-twiddle.com/41cd9541ca23835539414c3f58f4237d?openFiles=styles.app.css%2C) I just defined class for `red` and `blue` and you can see that what you tried is working. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly assign properties to `class` attributes too. You dont need to use `bind-attr`.

For `<td class={{classNameProperty}}>`, if `classNameProperty` is `red` then you will get `<td class="red">`.

For `<td calss={{if isActive 'form-control active' 'form-control'}}` ,
  if `isActive` is  truthy value then you will get `<td class="form-control active">` and if its false then you will get `<td class="form-control">`.

Refer:
https://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_bind-attr

Comment: I think I am very close, but it is still not changing the color of that <td> and I get no errors or nothing to show me what is wrong. Like he is not recognizing the action "toggleColor". Any ideas?

Comment: Update what you tried in the question especially `index.js`route file. You can reproduce it in https://ember-twiddle.com/. so that it will be easy to pin point the mistake...

Comment: Everything is cool, thank you very much! :) I just needed to use bgcolor attribute not class to change the color. :) I am sorry for rushing! :)

Comment: No problem you post your code and issue some one will help you.